# Weird ldap filter (member<==>CN=usera,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=abc,DC=corp,DC=xyz,DC=com)

Tags: active-directory, ldap, cpu-usage, domaincontroller

On a domain controller, I see this request:

Client:
10.168.x.y:51388 
Starting node:
DC=abc,DC=corp,DC=xyz,DC=com
Filter:
 (member<==>CN=usera,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=abc,DC=corp,DC=xyz,DC=com) 
Search scope:
subtree 
Attribute selection:
name 
Server controls:

Visited entries:
55683 
Returned entries:
14 
Used indexes:
Ancestors_index:12171:N; 
Pages referenced:
355546 
Pages read from disk:
0 
Pages preread from disk:
0 
Clean pages modified:
0 
Dirty pages modified:
0 
Search time (ms):
344 
Attributes Preventing Optimization:
member
User:
xx\usera

This request caused high CPU usage on a Win 2016 DC.

However, when I run this in ldp, it does not return any result. If I use the filer (member=…..), it returns some result. But if I use the filter (member<==>…….), it does not return anything.

I haven't seen this kind of filter before. Is this a valid filter? If it is not, how come this return 14 entries as seen in the event log?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is definitely not a valid filter, but it's probably a notation used in the logs for an extended search as pointed out by @gabriel-luci

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. I am able to use :1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941: and get the entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never looked at the server logs, but I wonder if they used the `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN` object identifier (OID) and that's just the way it shows up in the logs. The LDAP query you would actually use is this:

```
(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=usera,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=abc,DC=corp,DC=xyz,DC=com)
```

There's more info about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/search-filter-syntax#operators), but basically, that will search for any group that has the user as a member, but recursively. So if `Group A` contains `Group B` and `Group B` contains `usera`, then that search will return both `Group A` and `Group B`. So yes, that would be a somewhat CPU-heavy search, but also a very useful one sometimes.

So try that and see if you see the same thing in your logs when you try it.

From the perspective of the application, sometimes that kind of search is used for permissions, since, if we use my example above, if `Group A` is given permissions to the application, then `usera` should be allowed in even though they're not a *direct* member.

However, there are other ways to do it, depending on what the application is written in. For example, a user's Windows logon token will already contain a recursive list of the SIDs of every group they're a member of. But there might not be a logon token available when this information is needed.